# Combine scripts and update csv file

Tags: powershell, pipeline

How could I combine these two, to get an output **Jose is a Boy** and update it on the csv file.

```
cls
$response = Read-Host -prompt "Do you want to update a csv file? Yes/No" 
#to get input from the user
If ($response -eq "Yes")
{
   $csvfile = Read-Host "Enter a csv filename" #to get the csv filename
   Import-Csv $csvfile
   
}
else {
   Write-Host "Exit."
}
```

And this one

```
Import-Csv -Path $csvfile | ForEach-Object {
    If ($_.ColumnA -eq 'Jose'){
        $_.ColumnB = 'Boy'    
    }
    else{
        $_.ColumnB = 'Girl'
    }
    $_
} | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Output must be like this:

```
Do you want to update csv file? Yes/No
Enter csv filename: example.csv

ColumnA ColumnB
------- -------
Jose    Boy
Maria   Girl
Jose    Boy
Maria   Girl
Jose    Boy
Jose    Boy
Jose    Boy
Maria   Girl
```

Comment: Sorry, but can you rephrase your question?

Comment: I have 2 program I want it to combine so that I can get the output.

Comment: I would recommend [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67766698/edit), adding all the information provided in your comments here and removing them, if you're not sure how to format the code we will do that for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for, I added comments in the code to help you understand.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

cls
$response = Read-Host -prompt "Do you want to update a csv file? Yes/No" 
#to get input from the user

if($response -eq 'No'){break} # This will end your script.

# A cool way to ask a user to select a file is a OpenFileDialog
# with this you make it easier to find the file you're looking for
# if you still prefer the Read-Host method, uncomment below line
# and remove the OpenFileDialog code.

# $csvfile = Read-Host "Enter a csv filename"

# Remove from here
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$browse = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog -Property @{ 
    InitialDirectory = [environment]::GetFolderPath('MyDocuments')
    Filter = 'Comma Separated Value File (*.csv)|*.csv'
    Multiselect = $false
}
$browse.ShowDialog() > $null

# If no file was selected (Cancel button or Close button)
# end the program
if(-not $browse.FileName){break}

# Up to here if you do not wish to use this method.

# If using OpenFileDialog use this:
$csv = Import-Csv $browse.FileName

# If using Read-Host use this:
$csv = Import-Csv $csvfile

$newCsv = $csv | foreach-object {

    if($_.ColumnA -eq 'Jose')
    {
        # Using a Try {} Catch {} block in the conditions because
        # if the CSV does not contain a Column with name 'ColumnB'
        # doing $_.ColumnB = 'Boy' would throw an error.
        try
        {
            $_.ColumnB = 'Boy'
        }
        catch
        {
            # The Catch block here will handle the error by adding a new 'Member'
            # to the object with the desired Value and the desired Column Name.
            $_ | Add-Member -MemberType 'NoteProperty' -Name 'ColumnB' -Value 'Boy'
        }
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            $_.ColumnB = 'Girl'
        }
        catch
        {
            $_ | Add-Member -MemberType 'NoteProperty' -Name 'ColumnB' -Value 'Girl'
        }
    }

    $_
}

# Here you can see the result of the new CSV
$newCsv | Format-Table

# In case you need to export these to a new CSV or replace the existing one
$newCsv | Export-Csv 'path/to/newCsv.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: where is the start of OpenFileDialogCode I wish to remove it instead use the Read-Host?

Comment: @CatlynMadera I edited my code, check the comments. Remember to change this: `$csv = Import-Csv $csvfile` too.